# Looping infinito em relacionamento bidirecional - ManyToMany

Tags: api, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Estou construindo uma API Rest em SpringBoot. Nela tenho 2 classes que se relacionam, e ao eu fazer um `get` em uma delas elas me retornam um *looping* infinito através de suas chaves estrangeiras

Já tentei usar o `fetchType.Lazy` porém sem resultados.

Elas se relacionam através de um item pois essa categoria será de um projeto posterior.

Classe User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class UserListed {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "cd_user")
private Long id;

@Size(max = 50)
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "nm_user")
private String name;

@Size(max = 21)
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "nm_username", unique = true)
private String username;

@Size(max = 120)
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "nm_email", unique = true)
private String email;

@Size(max = 255, min = 8)
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "nm_password")
private String password;

@Size(max = 120)
@Column(name = "ds_biography")
private String biography;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "category_user",joinColumns = 
    {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_user")}, inverseJoinColumns = 
    {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_category")})
private List<Category> categories;
// get e set
```

Classe Categoria

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cd_category")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 24)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "nm_category")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cd_project")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "category_user", joinColumns = 
            {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_category")}, inverseJoinColumns  =
            {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_user")})
    private List<UserListed> users;
    //get e set
```

Retorno:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "greatcode",
    "username": "@greatcodeGC",
    "email": "greatcode.gc@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$pIYyhZo/iUKtq99g.Mbl1eYns/ABQddhFxvxDIeZ/Id2JFra9xBNO",
    "biography": "Uma empresa criada por jovens estudantes de TI",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "ScrumMaster",
            "project": null,
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "greatcode",
                    "username": "@greatcodeGC",
                    "email": "greatcode.gc@gmail.com",
                    "password": "$2a$10$pIYyhZo/iUKtq99g.Mbl1eYns/ABQddhFxvxDIeZ/Id2JFra9xBNO",
                    "biography": "Uma empresa criada por jovens estudantes de TI",
                    "categories": [
                        { ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode [anotar](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) o relacionamento das suas entidades com `@JsonManagedReference` e `@JsonBackReference`:

- `@JsonManagedReference` é colocado na parte da referência que quer avançar na serialização. Ou seja, a parte que é serializada normalmente.
- `@JsonBackReference` é colocado na parte da referência que não quer na serialização. Ou seja, a parte que será omitida.

No seu caso, anote o relacionamento de `User` com `Category` com `@JsonManagedReference` e de `Category` com `User` com `@JsonBackReference`.

Outra alternativa é usar o `@JsonIgnore` em um dos lados do relacionamento:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "category_user", joinColumns = 
        {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_category")}, inverseJoinColumns  =
        {@JoinColumn(name = "cd_user")})
private List<UserListed> users;
```

Porém, sugiro que a melhor maneira de lidar com este problema é não serializar as entidades; crie uma classe "DTO" (`UserResponse`, `CategoryResponse`, etc), escolha apenas os campos que deseja retornar e faça a conversão os valores das entidades para estes DTOs. Assim, as alterações que realizar na entidade não afetarão sua API.